# Passing arguments to a model driven app in PowerApps

Tags: url, powerapps, app-id, powerapps-modeldriven

I know parameters can be passed to a canvas app in PowerApps via URL for the app.
Can anyone please guide me on how to do this for model driven apps. I searched for if there exist any way to achieve this, but so far no luck.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways it can be done.

For setting fields on the form (that are on the form) :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/set-field-values-using-parameters-passed-form

and for creating your own parameters and passing them for use in JavaScript or PCF:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/configure-form-accept-custom-querystring-parameters